# Hawaiian Airlines Boarding/Deboarding Music

Tags: air-travel, identify-this, hawaiian-airlines

What is the cultural music played on Hawaiian Airlines flights during boarding/deboarding? This is the music played on the monitors of the seats (the music videos) and over the public speaker of the plane.

Just in case the music changes, I'm looking for what it was as of December 2017 / January 2018.

Comment: You already have a popular answer, but it's not accepted yet, so hopefully it's acceptable to add: as they say, "there's an app for that". Shazam used to be popular, but even Google assistant can do it these days.

Answer (score 10):

I just returned from a 5 day trip to Oahu in January of 2018.  The song is "Hawaiian Cowboy" by Willie K.  Here is a [link to the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNJRd55UYPk).

Answer (score 4):

Hawaiian has changed their music: as of late 2019, it's now the rather haunting **Life in these Islands** performed by Kawika Kahiapo.  Here's the official Hawaiian Airlines video for it: https://youtu.be/G4rf9y0xukk

Answer (score -5):

It's possible that Hawaiian Airlines may have used a mix of traditional Hawaiian music and other genres to create a soothing and culturally relevant atmosphere for passengers. To get the most accurate and up-to-date information, I recommend reaching out to Hawaiian Airlines directly or checking their official website for details on their in-flight entertainment and music offerings.

Comment: Hi Tony, is your answer from ChatGPT?

Comment: That contradicts the other answers. Can you edit to tell us why they are wrong?

Comment: I've flagged this as "very low quality" because it has no substance beyond "I don't know, ask the airline", dressed up with flowery writing.

Comment: It's me, it seems my answer makes you think I'm AI. It's really sad